# Index multiple entities into one index using Hibernate Search

Tags: hibernate-search

Is it possible to Index multiple entities within same index using Hibernate Search? I have 3 entities COUNTRY,COMPANY and SECTOR. These entities are not related to each other. A user can search across all these entities similar to a google search. I want all entities indexed in one Lucene directory.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Just use the same index name within the @Indexed annotation:

```
@Indexed(index="foo")
```

Comment: Hi Hardy thanks for ur ans but,even i did the same thing now it is indexing into one  &  i'm getting result as under country--country data,under company-company data,under sector--sector data but i don't want this way i'm looking   my result as all three tables data comes under foo in sequence r lucene ranking like A,B,C,D,......

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking in his case. You always get managed entities back from a search (unless you are using projections). Per default all indexed entities are targeted or you explicitly specify the targeted entities via the vararg parameter. Maybe it would help if you post the code for your entities and the query you try to run.